# Refresh session state on button press

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, session

I have a  button that when pressed, looks for a value based on a listbox choice and if it finds records in the table, it takes that value from listbox and puts it into a session, refreshes the page and the session is then used as a data source, ie. find where session = session.
Now what happens is if i want to do two consecutive searches, the button doesnt store new session, instead it takes the old session. So if I search for x first, then y, it will add x when page is refreshed.

```
 protected void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Driver WHERE City = '" + JourOrigin.SelectedItem + "' ";//retrieves driver names from table
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        if(Session["city"] != null)

        {
            Session["city"] = null;
            JourOrigin.SelectedValue = null;

        }
        else
        {
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {

            Session["city"] = JourOrigin.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/FindDriver.aspx");
            NoCity.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                DriversJourney.Items.Clear();
                DriversJourney.Items.Add("No Drivers in selected city, try another city");
                NoCity.Visible = true;
                NoCity.Text = "No drivers in selected city, please try another city";
            }

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I managed to clear the session if there is a session already, but I have to press value twice to store it. Is it possible to "refresh" a session every time the button is pressed?

Comment: in your code `if(Session["city"] != null)` you clear the income value as well. Remove `JourOrigin.SelectedValue = null;` from this IF. Second, the session is stored in a ELSE, so if the session is not null your code will erase the session and DONT execute the another step of code. Change your if and remove the else. Let the code be executed after the IF.

Comment: I need the else because the session will clear once i hit the button, it doesnt check if the session is null

Answer (score 0):

You must try this code:

```
protected void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Driver WHERE City = '" + JourOrigin.SelectedItem + "' ";//retrieves driver names from table
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    if(Session["city"] != null)
    {
        Session["city"] = null;
    }

    if(dr.HasRows)
    {
        Session["city"] = JourOrigin.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/FindDriver.aspx");
        NoCity.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        DriversJourney.Items.Clear();
        DriversJourney.Items.Add("No Drivers in selected city, try another city");
        NoCity.Visible = true;
        NoCity.Text = "No drivers in selected city, please try another city";
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: If I do this, all it does instead of clearing the dropdown it keeps the old session unless i click twice on the search